# Appending text to the inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen the following syntax in  pre-existing code.

```
$("#offers").children().last().html(
  $("#offers").children().last().html() + "!");
```

Is there a smoother approach to **append** some text to the HTML? Is there also a nicer way to refactor the following?

```
$("#offers").children().last().html(
  "!" + $("#offers").children().last().html());
```

And how about this?

```
$("#offers").children().last().html(
  "!" + $("#offers").children().last().html() + "!");
```

My suggestion is the following but I'd like to see if there's something even neater.

```
var old = $("#offers").children().last().html();
var prefix = "";
var suffix = "";
$("#offers").children().last().html(suffix + old + prefix));
```

Comment: Hint: Googling _jquery + <your exact title>_ yields several results answering exactly this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use prepend and append

```
$('#offers').children().last().prepend("!");
$('#offers').children().last().append("!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$("#offers").children().last().html(function(index, oldHtml){
    return oldHtml + '!';
});
```

or as per your suggestion:

```
var prefix = "!";
var suffix = "!";
$("#offers").children().last().html(function(index, oldHtml){
    return suffix + oldHtml + prefix;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use ".append()" method provided by jQuery. ([Api append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/))

Try:

```
$("#offers").children().last().append("!");
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    // Simply remove one time from DOM.
     var elem = $("#offers").children().last();
     var old_html = elem.html();
     var prefix = "";
     var suffix = "";
     elem.html( suffix + old_html + prefix);
```

Comment: I fail to see the difference to my suggestion. What do I miss?

Comment: @KonradViltersten retrieving element from DOM only one time[var elem]

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the DOM object with `jQuery.get()` method and use good old `innerHTML`:

```
$("#offers").children().last().get(0).innerHTML += "!";
```

Or you can use `jQuery.append()`

```
$("#offers").children().last().append('!');
```

In the second case use `jQuery.prepend()`

```
$("#offers").children().last().prepend('!');
```